# How can I remove punctuation from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
wordcount = {}
    for vocab in file.read().split():
        if vocab not in wordcount:
            wordcount[vocab] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[vocab] = wordcount[vocab] + 1
    for (word,number) in wordcount.items():
        print (word, number)
print (word_count(0))
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can I remove the punctuation from the dictionary when I print it? When I print it returns a lot of punctuation at the end of words

Comment: Maybe you should remove punctuation from the text before putting words in the dict.

Comment: As polku said, you should be [stripping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the punctuation from words before adding them to the dict. Also consider using a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a plain dict.

Answer (score 0):

As PM 2Ring notes, a `Counter` object would be useful here or simply a `defaultdict` from the `collections` library.  We can use the regular expression package `re` for a more powerful `re.split()` or simply `re.findall()`:

```
from re import findall, IGNORECASE
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

wordcount = defaultdict(int)

file = open("license.txt")

for vocab in findall(r"[A-Z]+", file.read(), flags=IGNORECASE):
    wordcount[vocab.lower()] += 1

for word, number in sorted(wordcount.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
    print(word, number)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
the 77
or 54
of 48
to 47
software 44
and 36
any 36
for 23
license 22
you 20
this 19
agreement 18
be 17
by 16
in 16
other 14
may 13
use 11
not 10
that 10
...
```

There are always trade-offs: you might want to fine tune the pattern to allow hyphenated words or apostrophes, depending on your application.

Reading the entire file in and processing it is fine if the input file is relatively small.  If not, read it line by line in a loop with `readline()` instead and process each line in turn.